# Disable geolocation browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm writing an integration test using QUnit, and in my webapp if geolocation is not available, (I use `if (navigator.geolocation)` to detect if is present or not, but I want to disable it in order to implement the test when geolocation is not available.

I tried `navigator.geolocation = undefined` but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really "disable" [`navigator.geolocation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation) since it's a read-only property.

Instead, you could create a wrapper that checks for certain functionality and then mock it up for your tests.

```
var supports = {
  geolocation: !!navigator.geolocation // will be `true` if geolocation is defined
};

// In your tests...
supports.geolocation = false;
executeTest();
```